# Ajax won't call PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax function which should call search-engine.php but nothing happen. 
Here my code:

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax(){
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'search-engine.php',
     data: {userInput: searchInput},
     success: function(){
     alert('works');
     },
     error: function(){
     alert('something went wrong');
     }
    }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$userInput = $_POST("userInput");
echo $userInput;
?>
```

And my input is inside a form tag with method post. If is important.

Comment: $userInput = $_POST['userInput'];

Comment: Open your console and read the error message. Then go to [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and learn how `$.ajax()` works.

Comment: Of course there is POST I'm sorry my fault @nevermind

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen There is no error messages. And I really don't know why. And why my script don't work

Comment: Any reason you are using `POST` instead of the default `GET`? Do you know the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript is all messed up. This is how it ought to look (compare and contrast with your code). And [read the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)!

```
 $.ajax('search-engine.php', {
      type: 'POST',
      data: { userInput:searchInput }
 }).done(function () {
      alert('works');
 }).fail(function () {
      alert('something went wrong');
 });
```

And in the PHP you are using `(` and `)`. You have to use the `[` and `]` characters. If you are not getting any errors then you should turn on errors!

```
<?php
$userInput = $_POST["userInput"];
echo $userInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your ajax call is wrong.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

You have to pass the config object to the ajax function:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'search-engine.php',
     data: {userInput: searchInput},
     success: function(){
         alert('works');
     },
     error: function(){
         alert('something went wrong');
     }
});
```